# Subscribe SharePoint online integrated add-in workflow to library on site using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, visual-studio, csom, app

Is there a way to subscribe workflows from integrated apps/add-ins using C# CSOM?

Currently I have:

1. Created an integrated app/add-in in visual studio
2. Added the app package to the app catalog in SharePoint Online
3. Added the app/add-in to a site
4. Subscribed a workflow from the app/add-in to a document library in the site

So far I have not been able to find a csom call that lists any information about integrated workflows.

The code below finds normal workflows but misses integrated ones:

```
 var workflowDeploymentService = workflowServicesManager.GetWorkflowDeploymentService();

        var publishedWorkflowDefinitions = workflowDeploymentService.EnumerateDefinitions(false);
        context.Load(publishedWorkflowDefinitions);

        context.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (var pwd in publishedWorkflowDefinitions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pwd.DisplayName + " " + pwd.Id);
        }
```

Once i have the guid i intend to use the code below to associate the workflow. I have used this code to subscribe workflows in another project.

```
var workflowSubscriptionService = workflowServicesManager.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService();

        WorkflowSubscription newSubscription = new WorkflowSubscription(context)
        {
            DefinitionId = workflow_id,
            Enabled = true,
            Name = "Add To Report Tracker V"
        };

        var startupOptions = new List<string>();

        // automatic start
        /*
        startupOptions.Add("ItemAdded");
        startupOptions.Add("ItemUpdated");
        */

        // manual start
        startupOptions.Add("WorkflowStart");

        newSubscription.EventTypes = startupOptions;

        newSubscription.SetProperty("HistoryListId", "workflowHistoryListId");
        newSubscription.SetProperty("TaskListId", "workflowTaskListId");

        workflowSubscriptionService.PublishSubscriptionForList(newSubscription, list_id);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Here is a [link](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/working-with-the-sharepoint-workflow-services-client-side-object-model) that I have been working from for csom and workflow services.

The site I have added the app/add-in to has over 1000 document libraries in it, and so I want to write a c# program that loops over each document library subscribing the integrated app/add-in workflow using CSOM.

Answer (score 0):

The context was the problem. To subscribe integrated app workflows you need to be in the app web context rather than the site context. So you should use:

https://{sharepoint base url}/{site app is added to}/{app name}/

When instantiating the client context.